# How to Update Docker Image (GitHub)

Tags: python, github, telegram-bot

I created a Docker image from a GitHub repo. I made some changes so I want to update docker image. How to do that?

I am using aws ubuntu.

Comment: Your question is not answerable. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

after doing changes in your docker image, when you do **docker commit** it will save the a new images

Usage

> docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]

Comment: I mean I made changes in that repo .. now I want to update it .

Comment: Your question is confusing, you wan't to update the github repo or you want to update the image?